# Remover opção em branco select option angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

Boa tarde, necessito remover a linha em branco que vem como default no select do angularjs, gostaria de colocar um valor default no lugar da linha em branco. Pesquisei em diversos fóruns e testei muitas opções mas nada funcionou. podem me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>SubClasse</label>
    <select ng-model="modelcompraevenda.subClasse" class="form-control">
        <option  ng-selected="data.unit == 2"  ng-selected="true"  ng-repeat="z in modelcompraevenda.listSubClasses" value="{{z.id}}">{{z.descricao}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar!!
segue solução:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <label>SubClasse</label>
     <select ng-model="modelcompraevenda.subClasse" class="form-control" style="z-index:0" ng-options="z.descricao for z in modelcompraevenda.listSubClasses track by z.id">
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa setar um valor inicial para seu modelo, dessa forma:

```
$scope.modelcompraevenda.subClasse = $scope.modelcompraevenda.listSubClasse[0];
```

Comment: não deu certo :/

Comment: a sua resposta complementa a minha, obrigado meu caro!